# Filter Array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a list with that contains a list of objects. Each object has 4 properties on it.  There is a checkbox list with the unique values of two of the properties, this helps build my filter array.

the **Filter** might end up looking like this:

```
[
    {
        prop: 'username',
        val: ['max', 'sam']
     },
     {
        prop: 'color',
        val: ['blue', 'green']
     }
]
```

The **list of objects** would look something like this:

```
[
    {
        username: 'sam',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        username: 'jimmy',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        username: 'sam',
        color: 'black'
    },
    {
        username: 'max',
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        username: 'max',
        color: 'blue'
    }
]
```

The **Desired Result**

```
[
    {
        username: 'sam',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        username: 'max',
        color: 'green'
    },
    {
        username: 'max',
        color: 'blue'
    }
]
```

---

I feel like I'm going down a never ending `forEach` rabbit hole. I'm guessing I need some sort of recursion. Currently here is what I have:

```
var temporary = scope.transactions;

function getFilteredTransactions() {
    var filter = deviceFilterService.get();

    if (filter.length > 0) {
        var temp2 = [];
        angular.forEach(filter, function (fil) {
            //object
            angular.forEach(fil.val, function (filterValue) {
                //list on each object
                angular.forEach(temporary, function (transaction) {                                 
                    if (transaction[fil.prop] === filterValue) {
                        if (temp2.indexOf(transaction) === -1) {
                            temp2.push(transaction);
                        }
                    }
                });

                temporary = temp2;
            });
        });

        $log.debug(temporary);
        scope.transactions = temporary;
    } else {
        initialize();
    }
}
```

This is starting to work, the second time it goes through the property for `color` it ends up just wanting to add the exact same transaction to the `temp2` array. There has to be a better way to set this up, possibly through recursion.

Comment: This is not valid js: `{'max', 'sam'}` Update your question with a valid desired result. Also, change `username` to `name`, otherwise there's no way to match up the two.

Comment: (!temp2.indexOf(transaction)) should be (!temp2.indexOf(transaction) < 0) ?

Comment: Made a fiddle of what I think you're looking for - but didn't use your existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz32hka5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the format of the first list to a dictionary, i think if should get easier.

```
var dict = {};
angular.forEach(source1, function(ob){
  dict[ob.prop] = ob.val;
});


function getFiltered(ob){
  for(var prop in ob){
    if(dict[prop] && dict[prop].indexOf(ob[prop]) === -1){
      return false;
    }
  }
 return true;
};
```

and just call it as:

```
var temporary = scope.transactions.filter(getFiltered);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/T8RfOm?p=preview)**

---

Basically the first part converts:

```
[
    {
        prop: 'username',
        val: ['max', 'sam']
     },
     {
        prop: 'color',
        val: ['blue', 'green']
     }
];
```

to:

```
{ 
  username:['max', 'sam'],
  color:['blue', 'green']
 }
```

so that it makes the look up much easier.

Comment: I like this route a lot, very little code. My implementation is slightly different and keep getting errors of undefined, writing up a plunkr now

Comment: @JonHarding Sure, i just went with data in the question, probably may have to add some null checks

Comment: yes, the data will have properties that won't be filtered

Comment: @JonHarding alright please show me a plunker with more info...and replica... probably i did not get your actual expectation fully

Comment: @JonHarding **[Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/T8RfOm?p=preview)** is this what you expected

Comment: I added the if statement around `if(dict[prop]){` which has it working on the first load. I'm now clicking around in my filter to try to see how the filter works when it's dynamic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79075/discussion-between-jon-harding-and-psl).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the variable names here for clarity, but this will do what you're asking for:

```
        var values = {};
        angular.forEach(startingData, function(rawData) {
            angular.forEach(rawData, function(value, key) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(values[key])) {
                    values[key] = [];
                }
                if (values[key].indexOf(value) === -1) {
                    values[key].push(value);
                }
            })
        });
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
            result.push({prop: key, val: value})
        });
```

Comment: this creates an object the value being an arrray of strings, and the property being the key.  I need to filter the list like I mentioned above. This would be a better way to create the filter though

Comment: I misread the question. I took the "filtered" part above as the desired result. ignore this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate each key of the data the needs filtering, find the appropriate filter per that key, and check the value against the filter values:

```
$scope.transactions = $scope.transactions.filter(isItemValidFilter);

function isItemValidFilter(item) {
    var filters = deviceFilterService.get();

    //For each property in the data, get the correct filter from the list of filters
    var totalConditions = Object.keys(item).length;
    var correctConditions = 0;

    for (var filterKey in item) {
        var correctFilters = filters.filter(function(dataFilter) {
            return dataFilter.prop == filterKey
        });

        if (correctFilters.length) {
            //Ill assume only 1 filter, so just use the 0 index
            var correctFilter = correctFilters[0];
            var conditions = correctFilter.val;

            if (conditions && conditions.length) {
                //check the values!
                if (conditions.indexOf(item[filterKey]) > -1) {
                    correctConditions++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return correctConditions === totalConditions;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz32hka5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var temp2 = [], matched;

angular.forEach(temporary, function(item){
    matched = true;
    angular.forEach(Object.keys(item), function(key){
        angular.forEach(filter, function(filter){
            filter.prop == key && filter.val.indexOf(item[key]) == -1 && (matched = false);
        });
    });
    matched && temp2.push(item);
});

console.log(temp2)
```

**temporary** is the list of objects, **filter**: your filters

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/7wnae850/